# 2 неразрешенных внешних символа, хотя в заголовках они есть

Tags: php, c++, c, zend-framework, extension

Всем привет!

Имеется расширение для PHP. Его основной файл, предположим, extension.c. Есть так же дополнительный MemoryModule.c (ну и заголовки естественно), из которого он берет нужные для работы функции. В начале extension.c прописано `#include "dl_memory.h"` и `#include "MemoryModule.h"`, в MemoryModule.с - `#include "MemoryModule.h"` соответственно. В VS все компилится прекрасно (еще бы), однако когда пробую собрать уже с PHP - получаю ошибки:

```
Создается библиотека C:\PHP\sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-7.1.3\Release\php7.lib и объект C:\PHP\sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-7.1.3\Release\php7.exp
dl_memory.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_MemoryLoadLibrary"
dl_memory.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_MemoryGetProcAddress"
C:\PHP\sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-7.1.3\Release\php7.dll : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 2
```

Что самое интересное - оба этих самых "символа" находятся в MemoryModule.c, объявлены в заголовках MemoryModule.h и используются extension.c:

MemoryModule.h:

```
HMEMORYMODULE MemoryLoadLibrary (const void *, size_t);
```

MemoryModule.c:

```
HMEMORYMODULE MemoryLoadLibrary (const void *data, size_t size) {
```

extension.c:

```
handle = (HMODULE) MemoryLoadLibrary (Z_STRVAL_P (file), (size_t) Z_STRVAL_P (dlldata));
```

то есть вроде бы все в порядке, да и VS все устраивает, значит проблема в PHP? Что же ему может не нравится если VS все нравится? В MemoryModule.с нельзя добавить extension.h, это другой уровень совсем, да я и пробовал тем более...

Переносил модуль несколько дней подряд, а тут тупик такой просто(

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: "собрать с PHP" то есть расширение должно быть в составе исполняемого файла PHP? И еще, как и чем собраете PHP?

Comment: Да, php7.exp вроде не берет его, где-то их судя по всему нужно инициализировать, но не знаю где, под PHP еще не писал. Собираю дефолтным bison.exe c инструментами VC++ через nmake (https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2).

Comment: P. S. Да и вначале из обычной библиотеки все-равно нужно сделать расширение конкретно для PHP, поэтому все-равно нужно сначала собрать его с ним, просто в php.ini на этом этапе подключить не получится.

Comment: По ссылке сказано, что расширения должны хитрым способом конфигрурироваться, вы это сделали правильно?

Comment: Посмотрите в `makefile`, который для расширения с ним в папке должен быть, `MemoryModule.c` фигурирует где-нибудь.

Comment: Да вот ищу в сорцах других расширений, как у них заголовки подключаются, не вижу ничего необычного...

Comment: Где-то вычитал, что .h нужно положить в dep/include, но пока безрезультатно(

Comment: Оба-на! Оказалось, что в config.w32 нужно было вписать все файлы с, а я только основной добавил, думая, что остальные-то служебные, VS же их видела. Большое спасибо за желание помочь, Вы были вообще-то правы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас, скорее всего, при окончательной сборке файл `MemoryModule.c` вообще не компилируется и его объектный файл `MemoryModule.o` не компонуется с `PHP.dll`.

Почему это так, надо смотреть как вы собираете `PHP.dll`.

Comment: Комментарий для себя на будущее, и для других: в config.w32 (и config.m4 для никсов) в строке `EXTENSION ('ext_name', 'file1.c file2.c');` нужно вписать ВСЕ файлы, которые используются в проекте.